# Ruby round .5 not correct

Tags: ruby

Here what's bringing me trouble:

```
irb> (0.5).round # => 1 YES
irb> (0.075).round(2) # => 0.08 YES
irb> (9.075).round(2) # => 9.07 WHY???
```

What is going on? How come the result isn't `9.08`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Floating point is tricky. The decimal 9.075 can't be exactly represented as a float. This isn't specific to ruby.

The rounding algorithm in most cases (not including nans and the like)  works by multiplying the number by the appropriate power of 10, rounding, and then dividing by that same number. That multiplying by 10 results in some loss of precision.

Comment: or `sprintf('%.50f', 9.075)`

Comment: Can you explain why `0.075` is rounded to `0.08`? Its float value is also slightly *below* the decimal value.

Comment: Freddy & @Stefan, the C code in the doc for [Float#round](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Float.html#method-i-round) contains an extended comment that may shed light here.

Comment: @CarySwoveland good catch, but that comment is rather technical. Someone has to explain the algorithm in layman's terms. Any volunteers? ;-)

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I realized that also. Do you have any suggestion on how to write a method that would round my numbers as expected?

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger `BigDecimal(9.075.to_s).round(2).to_f` should work, but it's more like a hack. Maybe you should just use `BigDecimal` and avoid floats in the first place.

Comment: I'll go for this in the short term. :)

Comment: Another data point:  `7.075.round(2) #=> 7.08; 8.075.round(2)
 => 8.07`.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point number can not represent all number precisely. I advise to read [Floating Point - Representable numbers, conversion and rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding).

Since Ruby 2.2 you can use [`prev_float`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Float.html#method-i-prev_float) and [`next_float`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Float.html#method-i-next_float) to see which are the cloased representable floating points to a given number:

```
9.075.prev_float
#=> 9.074999999999998

9.075.next_float
#=> 9.075000000000001
```

As you see `9.075` is between to `9.075000000000001` and `9.074999999999998`, therefore the mean is at `9.0749999999999995` and therefore `9.075` rounds *down* to `9.07`.

Comment: This doesn't explain `0.075`. Its `prev_float` and `next_float` values are `0.07499999999999998` and `0.07500000000000001`. The mean is `0.074999999999999995`, but it rounds *up* to `0.08`

Answer (score -1):

This has to deal with the way ruby deals with Float. If you convert to Rational it rounds to the closest number : `(0.075).to_r.round(2) #=> (7/100)` and `9.075.to_r.round(2) #=> (907/100)`

More details on the floating point logic (logic used to internaly store floats) : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Comment: The conversion to Rational is already "lossy", i.e. `(0.075).to_r` is not equal to `75/1000r`